# Show that $F$ cannot have more than one proper subfield

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields

> Let $p$ be a prime and $F$ a field with $p^2$ elements. Show that $F$ cannot have
> more than one proper subfield

What I have so far: Since $F$ is a field, $F$ is an abelian group under addition. Also, the number of elements in a proper subfield of $F$ must be $p$.  How can I prove that this subfield is unique? Is this way the correct?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** You're right that the proper subfield of $F$ must contain $p$ elements. It also must contain $1,$ and therefore $1+1, 1+1+1,$ etc.

Comment: I think I follow you. Since the subfield contains $1$, it also contains the elements generated by $1$. So any other proper subfield will do the same, right?